# Javascript style.background not allowing me to adjust size of image

Tags: javascript, image, styles, cover

I want the background image of the red section to change when the user hovers over the blue section. 
[image: image here]

I have got this to work fine with the following code

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('scrolling-background-column-left').onmouseover = function()        
     {        
      document.getElementById('scrolling-background-section').style.background = "url('https://media.cntraveler.com/photos/5698051378d099fc122487e3/master/w_820,c_limit/Sunset-Beach-Oahu-cr-getty.jpg') no-repeat center";
     };

     document.getElementById('scrolling-background-column-left').onmouseout = function()        
     {        
      document.getElementById('scrolling-background-section').style.background = "";
     };
</script>
```

However [image: this] is the result when i hover over the blue section. Is there a way to make the image span across the entire section/whole width of the page? I have tried adding `cover` to the code however this doesn't seem to work, if i try changing the size of the image through the code it breaks everything.

Comment: `cover` should work. What is your code when you tried adding `cover` to background?

Comment: A question: Have you already achived the target picture with pure html and css? If so, you could use javascript to make the additional changes.

Comment: @reporter as far as I know this cant be done using html/css, I need to change the background for one section while hovering over a different section.

Comment: @jaye document.getElementById('scrolling-background-section').style.background = "url('https://media.cntraveler.com/photos/5698051378d099fc122487e3/master/w_820,c_limit/Sunset-Beach-Oahu-cr-getty.jpg') no-repeat cover center";

Comment: @JohnnyMcClorey: The final look must be possible with html and css, because Javascript just change the node values n browsers dom tree.

Comment: @reporter do you have any suggestions as of how? Are you suggesting I add background-size: cover to the css? Because I have already tried this

Comment: You cannot add a size for background images. May be you should provide a minimal runnable example for a better help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cover` should work in your case. When you use the `background` shorthand property, you need to have a `/` separating the position and size values:

```
document.getElementById('scrolling-background-section').style.background = "url('media.cntraveler.com/photos/5698051378d099fc122487e3/master/…) no-repeat center / cover";
```